# kafka connect - Consumer dealing with very low ingress rate

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is kafka connect suitable for cases where there is a very low message rate.
Ex: for a consumer, if there is a very low input message rate or periods when there is no messages being sent/received, can kafka connect handle these scenarios? Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I currently am running a connector that only produces maybe up to 10 messages a day, even though we've configured it to dump into hourly partitions, we only get 1 folder for when the messages arrive.

The important parameters are the partition rotation (if you are using TimeBasedPartitioner) and the rotate schedule ms - this one forces the connector to flush periodically.

You can also set a very low flush size to make the messages commit more frequently. If you have a higher flush size, then messages will be buffered until a commit happens. Even if the connect instance dies, it should resume from the previous offset while the data is retained in the topic

Comment: Thanks for the details. Will look into it.

Comment: Inorder to avoid having small files, a high flush size needs to be configured. Since the ingress rate is very low, I can have file commits set to few times a day which can still create small files. I see there is another config rotate.interval.ms apart from rotate.schedule.interval.ms. I believe using rotate.schedule.interval.ms would suffice to flush the commits periodically based upon server timezone.

Comment: Right, that's the one I hinted at in my answer